# Протокол парсера номеров

Tags: c#, design

Задача такая: существуют определенные строковые представления спец. номеров. Нужно сделать класс с методами 
bool IsCorrect(string number)
SomeObject Parse(string number)
string Extract(string someString)
bool Contains(string someString)

Класс является вспомогательным, и находится внутри сборки.

Вопрос в том что должны делать методы в случае некорректного аргумента ? Например если метод   IsCorrect принимает null, должен ли он проверять входной параметр на null или подразумевается что пользователи класса должны сами позаботиться об этом т.к. класс внутренним ? Или еще такая ситуация, методы Parse/Extract приняли некорректный параметр (номер не соответствует формату) что должен тогда делать метод, проверять входной параметр на корректность и бросать спец. исключение в случае если номер некорректный или пользователь класса заранее должен проверить передаваемый номер на короектность ?

Comment: с чекерами, возвращающими bool все просто и логично - истина только при правильном значении, остальное ложь. null - такое же неправильное значение, как и другие. По поводу парсеров, солидарен с @KoVadim, но можно еще подглядеть как сделан парсинг в самом .net, например Guid-ов, которые вполне себе номера специального вида. Там просто есть 2 метода: Parse, который падает с исключением при любом невалидном значении включая null, и TryParse, который прогоняет чекеры, и если все нормально, парсит.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вопросы, которые упоминаются в вопросе очень философские и все решают их по своему.

Есть такие способы.

1. **Не париться.** Делать как получается/как проще. без коментариев.
2. **Делать как получается**, но описывать поведение в документации. То есть написать явно - метод Parse должен получить не пустую строку и при этом валидную. Иначе поведение не определено.
3. **Стелить соломку.** Мой любимый. Суть в том, что делаем много различных функций/методов, которые могут проверять входные параметры. Теперь, в дебаг режиме эти методы вызываются всегда для всех входных параметров каждого метод. В релизе это все отключается. Для этого даже есть чудесная штука - [Assert](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ttcc4x86.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1). Но я часто делаю свой макрос для этого, который управляется с конфига/командной строки. В этом случае, если что то пошло не так, можно включить проверки и споймать нужное место у заказчика. Такие себе юнит тесты на живом заказчике. Конечно, эта функциональность активно пишет в лог все проверки (даже правильные. и все параметры записывает).